# Entity framework with foreign keys runs extremely slow

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, sqlperformance

Came across an Entity Framework code that creates objects with sub-objects using foreign keys from the DB.
The generated SQL query is immediate but the EF code runs forever...

1.checked that the FK of EF matches the FK of DB
2.checked that the datatypes of EF and DB match
3.checked that the FK have indexes

The EF code

```
DAL.NachshonDBDataContext oDB = Config.GetDB(); 
var oQuery =
          from oDALMentor in oDB.Mentors 
          orderby oDALMentor.User.sDisplayName
          select new
          {
              oDALMentor,
              oDALUser = oDALMentor.User,
              oDALSector = oDALMentor.LU_Sector,
              oDALAcademicInstitute = oDALMentor.LU_AcademicInstitute,
              oDALMentoringFramework = oDALMentor.LU_MentoringFramework,
              oDALMentoringCoordinator = oDALMentor.LU_MentoringCoordinator,
              oDALMentorQuestionnaires = oDALMentor.MentorQuestionnaires,
              oDALMentorLangs = oDALMentor.MentorLangs,
};
var result = oQuery.AsParallel().ToList(); // takes very long time
```

The generated SQL

```
SELECT * -- asterisk instead of all the generated fields
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.MentorQuestionnaires AS t7
    WHERE t7.gUserID = t0.gUserID
    ) AS value
FROM dbo.Mentors AS t0
INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS t1 ON t1.gUserID = t0.gUserID
INNER JOIN dbo.LU_Sectors AS t2 ON t2.nSectorID = t0.nSectorID
INNER JOIN dbo.LU_AcademicInstitutes AS t3 ON t3.nAcademicInstitueID = 
t0.nAcademicInstituteID
INNER JOIN dbo.LU_MentoringFrameworks AS t4 ON t4.nMentoringFrameworkID = 
t0.nMentoringFrameworkID
INNER JOIN dbo.LU_MentoringCoordinators AS t5 ON t5.nMentorCoordinatorID 
= t0.nMentorCoordinatorID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MentorQuestionnaires AS t6 ON t6.gUserID = t0.gUserID
WHERE t1.nStatus = 1
```

The query runs very fast and retrieves 1521 rows

Comment: Is it only the first time this code runs or is it consistently slow?

Comment: What happens when you don't call `AsParallel()`. Sometimes, depending on what you're trying to do, parallelization may result in slower execution of queries.

Comment: It runs slowly all the time and even when I omit the AsParallel() ...